# Getting broken image but it loads as a new tab

Tags: javascript, image, broken-image

I have the following little script that seems to work but two of the images appear broken.  They load when I right click and load as new tab:

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
    var counter = 0;
    var myPictures = [        
        'https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohhwJax6g4Y8BK30k/giphy.gif',
        'https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7aD5tv1ogNBtDhDi/giphy.gif',
        'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif'
    ];

    function nextPic() {
      counter += 1;
      if (counter > myPictures.length -1) {
        counter = 0;
      }
      target.src = myPictures[counter];
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="target" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif" width="107" height="98" />
  <input type="button" onclick="nextPic()" value="change image" />



    
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script seems to work, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move this line inside your `nextPic()` function so you don't try to grab that `div` before it gets loaded in the DOM.

```
function nextPic() {
  var target = document.getElementById('target');
  ...
```

Sometimes [`<script defer>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) will automagically wait for the DOM to load, sometimes it doesn't. It's JavaScript. It is what it is.

> #### defer
>
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded. This attribute must not be used if the `src` attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect. To achieve a similar effect for dynamically inserted scripts use `async=false` instead.

Here's a good [backstory on script loading](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/).

Comment: Did you trash your cache? Works just fine here.

Comment: How to do that in chrome?

Comment: F12 -> rightclick on the address bar reload button -> Empty Cache and Hard Reload

Answer (score 0):

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
    var counter = 0;
    var myPictures = [        
        'https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohhwJax6g4Y8BK30k/giphy.gif',
        'https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7aD5tv1ogNBtDhDi/giphy.gif',
        'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif'
    ];

    function nextPic() {
      counter += 1;
      if (counter == myPictures.length -1) {
        counter = 0;
      }
      target.src = myPictures[counter];
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="target" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif" width="107" height="98" />
  <input type="button" onclick="nextPic()" value="change image" />



    
 
</body>
</html>
```